# How to print the content of a list with a OnClick event?

Tags: list, functional-programming, elm

I've created a function that adds strings to a list, when a button is pressed.
Now the problem is that I can't Output the information that was pushed into the list.
I started to write a Submit function but I don't really get which model I have to include there. I want the output to be in the last div so there where now is "model.currentPlayer". In the Msg part I don't really get which variable I have to use there, since the full List should just be inserted in the div where I want to have my Output.

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, Attribute, button, text, h1, h2, h3, p, div, input, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (style)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput, onClick)




-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL
type alias Player =
  { player : String
  , strength : Int
  --, number : Int
  --, playernumber : Int
  --, placeholder : String
  --, counter : Int
  }


type alias Model =
  { content : String
  , teams : List Player
  , currentNumber : Int
  , currentPlayernumber: Int
  , currentPlayer : String
  , currentStrength : Int
  , placeholderPlayer : String
  , placeholderCounter : Int
  , placeholderStrength: Int
  }





init : Model
init =
  { content = ""
  , teams = []
  , currentNumber = 0
  , currentPlayernumber = 0
  , currentPlayer = ""
  , currentStrength = 0
  , placeholderPlayer = ""
  , placeholderCounter = 1
  , placeholderStrength = 0
   }



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = Change String
  | ChangeNumber String
  | ChangePlayernumber String
  | ChangePlayer String
  | ChangeStrength String
  | Add  
  --| Submit String






update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }

    ChangeNumber number ->
      { model | currentNumber = Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt number) }

    ChangePlayernumber playernumber ->
      { model | currentPlayernumber = Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt playernumber) }


    ChangePlayer player ->
      { model | currentPlayer = player }

    ChangeStrength strength ->
      { model | currentStrength = Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt strength) }

    Add ->
      { model | teams = ({player = model.currentPlayer, strength = model.currentStrength} :: model.teams), currentPlayer = "", currentStrength = 0 } 

   {- Submit player -> 
      { model | teams = } -}





-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
    playername = " Player" ++ String.fromInt (List.length model.teams + 1)
  in
  div []
    [ h1 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Team Creator" ]
    , p [style "font-family" "sans-serif", style "font-size" "15px", style "color" "grey"] [ text "With the Team Creator you can create teams. Insert information about the name and the strength(1-5) of every player and finally how many teams you want to have created by the Team Creator" ]
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Number of Teams:" ]
    , input [ placeholder  "Number", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#32db64", value (String.fromInt model.currentNumber), onInput ChangeNumber] []
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Players per Team:" ]
    , input [ placeholder  "Playernumber", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#32db64", value (String.fromInt model.currentPlayernumber), onInput ChangePlayernumber] []
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Name and Strength:" ]
    , div[] [ input [placeholder  playername, style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#488aff", value model.currentPlayer, onInput ChangePlayer] [] ]
    , input [ placeholder  " Strength", style "width" "300px", style "height" "30px", style "font-size" "25px", style "color"  "#4286F5", value (String.fromInt model.currentStrength), onInput ChangeStrength] []
    , div [] [ button [ style "background-color" "#66cc81", style "color" "white", style "margin-top" "20px", style "width" "300px", style "border-radius" "25px", style "height" "40px", style "font-size" "20px", style "margin-right" "70px", onClick Add] [ text "+ADD Player" ] ]
    , div [] [ button [ style "background-color" "#4286F5", style "color" "white", style "margin-top" "10px", style "width" "300px", style "border-radius" "25px", style "height" "40px", style "font-size" "20px", style "margin-right" "70px"{-, value model.teams, onClick Submit-}] [ text "SUBMIT!" ] ]
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact", style "margin-top" "20px"] [ text "Generated Teams:" ]
    , div []  (List.map (\{ player } -> div [] [ text player ]) model.teams)
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a view function that prints the names of each player in a list of divs like so:

```elm
playerListView : List Player -> Html Msg
playerListView players =
    let
        playerRow player =
            div [] [ text player.player ]
    in
    div [] (List.map playerRow players)
```

Using it in place of your last row in your example would look like this:

```elm
, playerListView model.teams
```

Or, if you want to keep it all in one line, the last line in your example could be:

```elm
, div [] (List.map (\{ player } -> div [] [ text player ]) model.teams)
```

Comment: do I have to define a second View for that or just insert your code after                         'view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  let
    playername = " Player" ++ String.fromInt (List.length model.teams + 1)
  in'

Comment: No, you could keep it all on one line if you'd like. I've added an example of doing so in the answer.

Comment: Ok thx but actually mean the part above with playerListView. I have edited my code and added your code to mine. I get an parsing error

Comment: Your original code had a number of parsing errors. I'd suggest fixing those first, before making modifications, then replacing the last div in your view with what I've proposed.

Comment: ok thx I think I have uploaded my whole code , which didn't have parsing errors. It now works. Thank u very much